# Whats wrong in my answer for this limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 3} (\frac{2x^3-5x^2-2x-3}{4x^3-13x^2+4x-3})$

Tags: calculus, limits

The answer is supposed to be 11/17 however I keep getting 22
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 3} (\frac{2x^3-5x^2-2x-3}{4x^3-13x^2+4x-3})$$

here's my solution:

1. since 3 is a zero of the the denominator it is divisible by x - 3
   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 3} (\frac{2x^3-5x^2-2x-3}{(4x^2-13x+4)(x-3)})$$
2. Used synthetic division by (x -3) on numerator
   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 3} (\frac{(2x^2+x+1)(x-3)}{(4x^2-13x+4)(x-3)})$$
3. Cancel (x-3)

What did I misunderstand here? Wolfram alpha isn't able to show the step by step solution so i can't figure it out, however its answer is also 11/17

1. Solve by replacing x by 3 = $\frac{22}{1}$

Comment: @DimitriSurinx I didn't multiply it. I factored both to cancel them out.

Comment: Is the original copied correctly?  I get a different $x^2$ term multiplying your denominator.

Comment: @vincentbelkin, my bad sorry.

Comment: @Mike the original question? or in one of my solution?

Comment: @Mike i double checked my solution and the question and its both copied correctly.

Comment: Don't be embarrassed, I have done silly things like this more times than I can count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denominator indeed is divisible by $x-3$ but the quotient you ended up with isn't quite correct:

$$
(4x^2-13x+4)(x-3) = 4 x^3-25 x^2+43 x-12
$$

If you used synthetic division you should end up with the factorization $(4 x^2-x+1)(x-3)$, which will give you the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

Unless something was copied wrong, it appears your denominator is equal to

$$(4x^2-13x+4)x-3\ne(4x^2-13x+4)(x-3)$$